# mysql_query() shows an error for an included PHP function

Tags: php, mysql

I have two files:

#### cart_function.php

```
function get_product_name($pid){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT product_name FROM product_table WHERE product_id='".$pid."'", $link);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $row['product_name'];
}
```

#### cart.php

```
<?php
    include('cart_function.php');
    $pid = $_GET['product_id'];
    $pname = get_product_name($pid);
    echo $pname;
?>
```

After I execute the `cart.php`, it shows an error

> supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource'

If I run the query directly in MySQL database it works perfectly. If I used the `get_product_name()` function directly in `cart.php`, again it's not working. But if I remove the function and use the code below, it works:

```
<?php
    $pid = $_GET['product_id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT product_name FROM product_table WHERE product_id='".$pid."'",$link);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $pname = $row['product_name'];
    echo $pname;
?>
```

Why?

Comment: where is database connection query?

Comment: If you want to use the global variable `$link`, you have to define it as global in `get_product_name`: `global $link;`

Comment: Please learn the basics of PHP, in this case: variable scope. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Does your function `get_product_name()` has access to `$link`?

Comment: connection file is included perfectly okay in the top of the page.I didn't put it here.Please assume it it in the top. If you really want to see that let me know i will post it

Comment: tip: use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or `mysql_fetch_array($qry,MYSQL_ASSOC)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
function get_product_name($pid){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT product_name FROM product_table WHERE product_id='".$pid."'",
                          $link);
```

You have written `$link`, but its value is not supplied. You have to pass this value in the function argument as you are passing `$pid` value, like this:

```
function get_product_name($pid,$link){
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You are directly using your database connection link as $link into function so it should be consider as local variable and it doesn't have anything.

2) so you need to declare $link as global in your function.

```
function get_product_name($pid){
        global $link;
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT product_name FROM product_table WHERE product_id='".$pid."'",$link);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        return $row['product_name'];
    }
```

3) Or you can pass $link as second argument of get_product_name($pid,$link)